# Find documents where all objects in array have specific value

Tags: json, mongodb

I have the following documents in MongoDB:

```
{
    name: "document1",
    data: [{
        name: "xxxxx",
        status: "delivered"
    },{
        name: "xxxxx",
        status: "In Process"
    },{
        name: "xxxxx",
        status: "Not Started"
    }]
},{
    name: "document2",
    data: [{
        name: "xxxxx",
        status: "delivered"
    },{
        name: "xxxxx",
        status: "delivered"
    },{
        name: "xxxxx",
        status: "delivered"
    }]
}
```

I want to find all documents where all objects inside the "data" array have the status "delivered", I used to use `$ne: 'Not Started'`, but now that more status options have been introduced, this doesn't work. Perhaps I could do a `$ne: $and` and include all negative options, but any new status will give issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$not` with `$elemMatch`

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "status": {
          $ne: "delivered"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "data.status": "delivered"
})
```

Here is fiddle  https://mongoplayground.net/p/digdoFC6yF0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/).

```
{
  $and: [
     { 'data.status': { $not: /Not Started/},
     {'data.status': "delivered"}
  ]
}
```

Note that $not must receive a regex and not just plain string.

Comment: would this work if it had an object with a different status other than "not started" or "delivered"?

Comment: this query gaurantees at least one 'delivered' and none 'not started' as you requested, so aslong as those two terms meet all other statuses can be within the object too.

Comment: I need to bring the documents where ALL status are exactly delivered, not where there's just one.

Comment: Can you add more conditions with other statuses similar to the 'not started', or is this not scaleable in your case?